# port definition in the play framework 2 application.conf

Tags: playframework-2.0

Does anybody know if it is possible to define the http port in the application.conf file of a Play Framework 2 app?

Answer (score 4):

In Play 2.x port is set while running/starting the application in the commandline (or in Play's console)

**Examples:**

1. Running application in dev mode with port `9123`:

   ```
   bash#: play "~run 9123"
   ```
2. Starting application in production mode on port `9321`:

   ```
   bash#: play "start 9321"
   ```
3. You can do the same by firing console first, and than writing the command placed in quotes in previous points:

   ```
   bash#: play 

   #(after console's load)
   [your-new-app] $ ~run 9123
   ```

of course if you are always using specified ports, it's good idea to write a shell script (or *.bat file on Windows) and name them like `run-local-dev.sh`, `start-local-prod.sh` etc.

Comment: @nico_ekito, thx as always :) btw most probably you will be interested with this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44211/play-framework?referrer=cX_a267rqoOtfSeeNAbG1Q2

Comment: if it´s not possible in the conf file I will change my scripts. thanks a lot guys.